# read-string for making new buffer

Tags: minibuffer

Am trying to use `read-string` to read a string from the user.  With that name I want to create a new buffer.

Have seen that `read-string` is sometimes called from within an `interactive` expression, but at other times, `read-string` is called outside on `interactive` expression.  How can I understand when to use one versus the other?

```
(defun workspace (name)
  "Make a new buffer with unique name."
  (interactive
    (read-string "Name: " initial nil nil))
 
  (let ( ($buf (generate-new-buffer name)) )
    (switch-to-buffer $buf)
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you should use one of the predefined argument types rather than calling `read-string` yourself. Did you read the docstring for `interactive`? It is long but complete.

```
(defun db48x/test-workspace (name)
  "Make a new buffer with unique name."
  (interactive "BName: ")
  (let (($buf (generate-new-buffer name)))
    (switch-to-buffer $buf)))
```

Comment: I know about `Code Characters` for `interactive`.  But seeing other's code, I also see calls that use, `read-string`, `completing read`.  But not much advice on when to choose what.  You have any advice on this?

Comment: Yes, avoid it when possible.

Comment: By default, `B` uses the name of a recently used buffer.  I want to avoid that when making the new buffer.  Can I get emacs to generate a unique name, but also let the user change it?

Comment: OP: Since you accepted this answer, and it doesn't correspond to what you asked, which is about using `read-string` (interactively or not), please retitle and reword your question to better fit the answer. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Your function has an argument `name` that would be supplied another way when called from lisp. Example:

```
(workspace "*foo*")
```

When called interactively, you need a way for the user to supply that argument which is what the `read-string` inside the `interactive` is for.

Other functions might need user input for a different purpose than filling in an argument and, in that case, no `interactive` will be involved:

```
(defun pointless-game ()
 "Ask user for a word, forever."
 (while 1
   (message "You said: %s\n"
            (read-string "Tell me a word: "))))
```